# Converting CString to unsigned long

Tags: c++

I am trying to convert a string to unsigned long. Here is the code

```
lCardNum = wcstoul(sCardNo.GetBuffer(sCardNo.GetLength()), NULL,0);
```

My  `sCardNo(CString)` value is 4294967359.
Why do I get `lCardNum(unsigned long)` as `4294967295`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that your unsigned long integer is 32-bits wide, then you are overflowing it. 0xFFFFFFFF is 4294967295. Your wanted 4294967359 is 0x10000003F, *i.e.*, it needs 33 bits.

Go for `unsigned long long` or `__int64` on a Windows box, lookup `_wcstoui64`.

Comment: I am using VC 6.0 and i tried using _wcstoui64. I am getting undeclared identifier. Do you know what has to be included.